# How do i specify a type a generic should not be in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a enum which implements both the trait From and Iterator this throws a compiler error:

```rust
impl<T, D> From<D> for List<T>
where
    D: Iterator<Item = T>
{
    fn from(iter: D) -> List<T> {
        // Unimportant
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for List<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // Unimportant
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `From<List<_>>` for type `List<_>`
  --> src/main.rs:52:1
   |
52 | impl<T, D> From<D> for List<T>
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> From<T> for T;
```

I haven't tried anything because i can't find anything on google

Comment: Since `List` implements `Iterator`, it could be `D`. So you end up with `impl<T> From<List<T>> for List<T>` which is just one case of `impl<T> From<T> for T`. Try implementing `IntoIterator` for `List<T>` instead.

Comment: @PitaJ `IntoIterator` works but im hoping for a better solution as i also want to implement `From<Vec<T>>` which still conflicts because a future version of rust will implement iterator for Vec

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way around this at the moment. Sounds like you want specialization: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844